# jQuery - script tag inside an iframe fails to update the iframe's content

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have the following html:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input id="msg" type="text" value="oldValue" />
        </form>
        <script src="http://jqueryjs.googlecode.com/files/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $().ready(function() {
                var m = $("#msg");
                alert(m.val()); // returns oldValue
                m.val("newValue"); // this doesn't make the browser show newValue instead of oldValue
                alert(m.val()); // returns newValue
                // and in the end, the browser still shows oldValue for the input
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code runs perfect, but when placed in a facebox (which just creates an iframe and shows it like a floating window), the code fails to update the input's content.

The parent also has jQuery, but that shouldn't influence anything I guess.

Any ideas why it's failing?

Comment: Have you tried getting the actual DOMElement instead of using jQuery's methods to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unable to replicate on Firefox 3, IE 7 or Chrome 2.  The code works fine (using `newValue` everywhere appropriate) regardless of whether it's in an iframe.

Have you tested your reduced sample implementation, as opposed to your original?  Because I suspect we have a problem where you think they're equivalent and they aren't.

Of course, the good news is that if your posted sample implementation works, then all you have to do is add in elements from your actual implementation until something breaks.

Comment: actually, in my implementation it's loaded from the same domain, the pasted version is just to be able to share it as my implementation is a lot bigger :)

Answer (score -1):

```
doc = xframe.contentWindow.document || xframe.document || xframe.contentDocument || xframe.contentWindow && xframe.contentWindow.document || null;

if(!doc)
{
  alert("Error");
  return false;
}

var m = $(doc).find("#msg");
```

Comment: if you would have carefully read my description, you would have found out that my script succesfully finds the #msg element, can read it's value, but can't set it.

Comment: ok, what I'm going on is an alternative to access the data. then this in your ability adapt. One thing is do not be useful, and something else that is a mistake.

Comment: If the item is in an iframe, you can only access using the iframe object . we must see if you got the same id in the iframe in the current document, ¿ok?